# Table doesn't exist after re-installing XAMP to a higher version

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I copied my `htdoc` files and `mysql/data` and installed a higher XAMPP (5.6) but after installation and i copied those folders back into the new XAMPP folders, in phpMyAdmin most of my tables give errors that Tables doesn't exist

Comment: You sure, you copyed both MyISAM and INNODB stuff?

Comment: @MIvanIsten please where can i find those folders? i backedup my whole old XAMPP folder

Comment: By default MyISAM tables are stored in files `DATABASENAME\TABLENAME.frm`, `DATABASENAME\TABLENAME.myd` and `DATABASENAME\TABLENAME.myi`. All INNODB tables are stored in the file `ibdata1`

Answer (score 1):

**Did you try Back up and Restore ?**

If you Upgraded the version of XAMPP and MySQL. A vanilla copy of mysql/data  will not work for databases.

You either need to backup under the old version and restore into the new version or use the mysql_upgrade processor.

Check this link for mysql upgrade "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html"